# What storage to use for passing data between pods?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working with kubernetes and I need to pass parquet files containing datasets between pods , but I don't know which option will work best.

As I know, persistent disk allows me to mount a shared volume on my pods, but with cloud storage I can share these files too.

All the process is hosted on google cloud.

Comment: As always, it depends of your requirements, latency, durability, I/O performance (...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to persist the data you have to use the file store of Google. Which will support the read write many.

> Persistent Volumes in GKE are supported using the Persistent Disks.
> The problem with these disks is that they only support
> ReadWriteOnce(RWO) (the volume can be mounted as read-write by a
> single node) and ReadOnlyMany (ROX)(the volume can be mounted
> read-only by many nodes) access modes.

Read more at : https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/readwritemany-persistent-volumes-in-google-kubernetes-engine-a0b93e203180

With disk, it won't be possible to share the data between **pods** as it will only support the **read-write** once. The single disk will get attach to a **single** node.

If you looking forward to mounting the storage like a `cloud bucket` behind the POD using `CSI driver`, your file writing **IO** will be very slow. Storage can give better performance with API.

You can create the NFS server in Kubernetes and use also which will provide support again to read writ many.

[Gluster FS](https://www.gluster.org/) & [MinIo](https://min.io/) is one of the option to use, however if looking for **managed** **NFS** use the **[filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares)** of Google.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with the local persistent volume when you need to pass large amount of data sets which will be cost effective and efficient.

Comment: With local persistent volume you reffer to a local volume mounted in a local machine? All the process is done in google cloud so I can't use any local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google Filestore as a file share. Then you need to:

1. create a Persistence Volume (PV)
2. create a Persistence Volume Claim (PVC)
3. Use the PVC with your pods

More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares)